# Como faço para incrementar dias à uma data em Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

Não tenho muita experiência com datas em Javascript, tão pouco com os frameworks mencionados:
Por enquanto o que consegui foi exibir a data atual no front-end usando a seguinte sintaxe:

```
this.myDate = new Date().toISOString();
```

Como posso trabalhar com essa data, de forma que consiga manipulá-la?

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o método [`setDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate):

```js
this.myDate = new Date();

this.myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + parseInt(30));

console.log(this.myDate.toISOString());
```